# Using GitBash -Installed gems?

Tags: ruby

Forgive the simplistic question (I am a Ruby Newbie) - I'm using GitBash - which command will show me which Ruby gems are installed?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
gem list --local
```

This is a gem-command, not a GitBash command.

To be honest, I don't see a relation between gem and git.